# Menaging file between iCloud and App Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, file-upload, icloud, icloud-drive

I have created a simple app that saves some info into txt file stored in the local App folder. I would like to enhance my aplication by adding a sync with iCloud.

I saved my "file.txt" to iCloud: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] setUbiquitous:YES itemAtURL:localFileURL destinationURL:ubiquityURL error:&error]` where `'localFileURL'` is the local path url of my file.txt and `ubiquityURL` is the iCloud destination URL (The place where the file will be saved).

2. But I need to replace the (saved) iCloud "file.txt".

I've already configured my app with iCloud Document service.

Could anyone forgive me an example on how let communicate between my app and iCloud drive in order to save and read a txt file? I've not found simple tutorials on line which provide me a simple solution.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation on using iCloud for files? Apple tells you how to do what you're asking. If there's something there you don't understand, ask a more specific question.

Comment: @TomHarrington Thanks for your answer, my question is to understand how can I import the 'file.txt' file that I saved to iCloud (with step 1) into my local folder of my App